# How to replace unpinned desktop icon on windows 8 metro screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I failed to shutdown my windows 8 pc properly and the next time i restarted my pc it went through a hard disk check and fixed some errors in my file system. After that, all pinned programs on my metro screen where gone. Is there a way to restore my pinned programs or restore the windows 8 default metro screen?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Start Screen, right click, All Apps. Select apps you want to pin by right clicking them, then select in the bottom menu, Pin to Start.

Comment: Better than my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

You could manually restore the apps by going to the Program Files folder in C:\ or whichever drive you are using and looking for which apps you want. Once you have found the app you can right click the app and click "Pin to Start". Just repeat that for every app that you want to pin.

More simply a system restore should do the trick. If it doesn't then follow the above steps ^